# How do I bring all previous values into a list in column in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to bring all the previous values of the column `b` to the column next to it as a list. My data looks like this,

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'b': [1, 3, 5, 7]})
>>> df
   a  b
0  1  1
1  2  3
2  3  5
3  4  7
```

And here is my expected output,

```
   a  b          c
0  1  1       None
1  2  3        [1]
2  3  5     [1, 3]
3  4  7  [1, 3, 5]
```

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use list comprehension with `if-else` statement:

```
df['c'] = [None if x == 0 else df['b'].iloc[:x].tolist() for x in range(len(df))]
print (df)
   a  b          c
0  1  1       None
1  2  3        [1]
2  3  5     [1, 3]
3  4  7  [1, 3, 5]
```

Or similar:

```
df['c'] = [None if x == 0 else list(df['b'])[:x] for x in range(len(df))]
print (df)
   a  b          c
0  1  1       None
1  2  3        [1]
2  3  5     [1, 3]
3  4  7  [1, 3, 5]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    df['c'] = [df['b'].values[:i] for i in range(len(df))]
```

I would, however, hesitate to use this on all but the smallest datasets.

Comment: Here I can see a use-case where `walrus operator` would make the code more precise and still be readable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'apply':

```
df["c"]= df.apply(lambda r: df.loc[:r.name-1,"b"].values,axis=1)

   a  b          c
0  1  1         []
1  2  3        [1]
2  3  5     [1, 3]
3  4  7  [1, 3, 5]
```

**Edit:**
Benchmarks

```
%timeit df.apply(lambda r: df.loc[:r.name-1,"b"].values,axis=1)         # mine, the slowest :-(
2.39 ms ± 158 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit [None if x == 0 else df['b'].iloc[:x].tolist() for x in range(len(df))]     # jezrael #1
231 µs ± 15.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit [None if x == 0 else list(df['b'])[:x] for x in range(len(df))]             # jezrael #2
65.3 µs ± 81.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%timeit [df['b'].values[:i] for i in range(len(df))]                    # selavy_, the fastest :-)
22.9 µs ± 1.44 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```